# finding mean from Cumulative Distribution function

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

I saw other similar posts where they do the integration from math stackexchange, but confused about this one since it is given in p. The following is my problem.

I was looking to find the mean from the following cumulative distribution function.

The function F(x) is

> 0 when z<o
>
> p when o $\leq$ z<2
>
> 1 when z$\geq$ 2

The answer given in the solution is `2(1-p)` but I couldn't follow the steps. I saw other similar posts where they do the integration from math stackexchange, but confused about this one since it is given in p.

appreciate your support. Thanks!

Comment: For a non-negative random variable, $\mathbb E[X]=\int\limits_{x=0}^\infty (1-F(x))\, dx$, which is quite easy here

Answer (score 1):

Your rv is discrete taking only the values $\{0;2\}$ with probability $\{p;(1-p)\}$, respectively, thus the expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=0\times p+2\times(1-p)=2(1-p)$$

To understand that your rv is discrete do a drawing of your CDF and observe that it has two "jumps" (two discontinuity points) in $x=0$ and $x=2$ and the sum of the two jumps is 1

The expectation is the area above the CDF: the area of  a rectangle with base $2$ and height $(1-p)$

Comment: thanku!! it makes the entire concept so much clearer now